# bad_certificate issue when moving from Spring Boot 2.x to 3.x

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, ssl-certificate

We have certificates for each service in the cluster for inter-service communication. When these certificates expires (some days), we start getting handshake errors. This started to happen after we moved from SpringBoot 2.7.6 to SpringBoot 3.1.2 (tried in 3.2.0 too) and Java 11 to 17.

There are several ¨types¨ of error messages, some showing SSLHandshakeException (as below) and others showing "PKIX path validation failed"

```
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate
```

When a service certificate is about to expire, it is automatically updated in the service pod, then a script replaces the keystores and calls an endpoint that will reload the keystore and restart tomcat connector. This was working before, but not now.

One thing that catches the eye when looking into the logs is the following message:

```
Connector [https-jsse-nio-8280], TLS virtual host [_default_], certificate type [UNDEFINED] configured from keystore [**/home/.keystore**] using alias [serverkey] with trust store [null]
```

but in application.properties we have something like:

```
 server.keystore=/keystore/serverkeystore.p12
 server.truststore=/truststore/truststore.p12
```

what make us think that when tomcat is restarting, it is trying to get the certificates from the wrong place, i.e. /home/.keystore, instead of the set in application.properties.

As a work around we created a class that implements TomcatConnectorCustomizer, that fills in all the necessary information found in application.properties, and created a ServletWebServerFactory bean that adds this customized connector to TomcatServletWebServerFactory and returns it.
Something like this:

```
    @Bean
    ServletWebServerFactory servletContainer(@Autowired SSLConnectorCustomization sslConnectorCustomization)
    {
        TomcatServletWebServerFactory tomcat = new TomcatServletWebServerFactory();
        tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers(sslConnectorCustomization);
        return tomcat;
    }
```

```
    private SSLHostConfig getNewSSLHostConfig(SSLHostConfig config)
    {
        SSLHostConfig newConfig = new SSLHostConfig();
        :
        newConfig.setTruststoreFile("/truststore/truststore.p12");
        :
        SSLHostConfigCertificate cert = new SSLHostConfigCertificate(newConfig, SSLHostConfigCertificate.Type.RSA);
        :
        cert.setCertificateKeystoreFile("/keystores/serverkeystore.p12");
        :
        newConfig.addCertificate(cert);
        return newConfig;
    }
```

When we moved to java 17 we made a lot of changes in code. In this particular point we replaced Apache http to http5, and I believe we might have missed something or some new configuration, I don't know. The fact is that it was working in 2.x and it not working in 3.x without the workaround. Actually it looks like an Spring issue, but as it is still giving the same result in SB 3.2 Do someone have any clue about what is really happening here and how to fix it without the workaround?